# Recent Cases Page layout

Tags: case

We have VF page for creating new cases & edit cases (through custom buttons); but the standard "New" button appears on the recent cases page layout;

1. Is there a way to remove the standard "New" button from the "Recent cases" page layout
2. Is there a way to customize that page layout

Can you suggest any workarounds

Comment: Can you override the 'new' page with your VFpage? This way anywhere a 'new case' button exists then your VF page will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Override the standard New and Edit pages with your custom VF page and whereever the new/edit buttons/links are shown they will direct to the correct (your VF page) page. No need to fiddle with the 'recent cases' tab at all (or related list buttons/links etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Recent 'Object' is a native layout and is not customizable.  You would need to generate a new VF page and replace the standard tab destination to change it's look/feel.  That includes removing the [New] button.  (The exception being, if you remove the CRUD permissions to prevent a user from creating a new record, the button will not display.)